# Suppose $R$ and $S$ are relations of a set $A$ prove that

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

a)If $R$ is symmetric, $R^{-1}$ is symmetric

b) If $R$ is anti-symmetric, $R^{-1}$ is anti-symmetric

c) If $R$ is reflexive, $R$ $∩$ $R^{-1}$ $≠ ∅$

d) If $R$ and $S$ are transitive, $R∩S$ is transitive.

$\  $

b) **Definition of symmetric**

$∀ a,b ∈ A, (a,b) ∈ R, (b,a) ∈ R --> a = b$

**Suppose** $\ $ $(a,b) ∈ R^{-1}, (b,a) ∈ R^{-1}$

**By the definition:** $(b,a) ∈ R, (a,b) ∈ R,$ **as $R$ **is symmetric**, $a = b$

**By the definition:** $(a,b) ∈ R^{-1}, (b,a) ∈ R^{-1} $ $\ $  **where** $\ $ $a = b$

$\  $

d) **Definition of transitive**

$∀ \  a,b ∈ A, (a,b) ∈ R, (b,c) ∈ R --> (a,c) ∈ R$

**Suppose** $(a,b) ∈ R∩S, (b,c) ∈ R∩S$

**By the definition:** $(a,b) ∈ R, (b,c) ∈ R,$  $\ $  **as $R$ is transitive**, $(a,c) ∈ R.$

**By the definition:** $(a,b) ∈ S, (b,c) ∈ S,$ **as $S$ is transitive,** $(a,c) ∈ S.$

**By the definition:** $(a,c) ∈ R^{-1}$

Comment: Relation $S$ never appears ?

Comment: @Evargalo There were more questions, But if I had put all, someone could complain for too many questions.

Comment: I can't follow your arguments.  Can you clarify, say, the "reflexive" one?

Comment: @lulu I don't even know where to start from to solve these questions, That was a try, If you can solve at least one I try the others.

Comment: Ok:  for reflexive, you have to add the assumption that $A$ is non-empty (otherwise it is false).  If $a\in A$ then $(a,a)\in R$ since R is reflexive.  But then $(a,a)\in R^{-1}$ hence $(a,a)\in R\cap R^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proofs could be more structured:

Suppose $R$ is symmetric.
We want to show $R^{-1}$ is symmetric. So take $(x,y) \in R^{-1}$.
By definition: $(y,x) \in R$.
As $R$ is symmetric: $(x,y) \in R$
So by definition again: $(y,x) \in R^{-1}$.
As $(x,y)$ was arbitrary, $R^{-1}$ is symmetric.

Now try to do the others in this style as well.

e.g. c):
We need to assume also that $A \neq \emptyset$, or else $R = R^{-1} = \emptyset$ and the assertion would be false.
Pick $a \in A$. Then $R$ is reflexive means $(a,a) \in R$.
But then also $(a,a) \in R^{-1}$ as well.
So $(a,a) \in R \cap R^{-1} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved 2, Could you check if They are correct ?

Comment: @hjx in b) the last "where" should be "then". d) is fine.